# Ajax call to retrieve hashmap

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, rest

I have a hashmap which I have converted into a JSONObject. This JSONObject I am retrieving via a REST api using an AJAX call. What I wish to know is that how will the ajax look like in order to get the JSONObject which I can use afterwards.

My ajax call looks like this :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : '...',
    method:'GET',
    scope : this,
    success : function(result, request) {
        console.log("2");
        var data = Ext.decode(result.responseText)[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            console.log("4. ");
        }
    }
})
```

The error which appears is

> Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

Comment: Use `console.log(result)` to see what format the response is in

Comment: Heres the response :       Object { request: Object, requestId: 1, status: 200, statusText: "OK", getResponseHeader: .createResponse/d.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .createResponse/d.getAllResponseHeaders(), responseText: "", responseXML: XMLDocument }    I dont know what to make of it

Answer (score 0):

result.responseText returns the Invalid JSON String.Use this code

`var responseArray = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
var data = responseArray.data;
console.log(data);`

data variable will contain the JSON Object.